# Keep Matlab from stepping into built in functions during dbstop if error

Tags: matlab, debugging

I use `dbstop error` a lot when working in Matlab. A good portion of the time, a mistake causes errors to be thrown *inside* of built-in [m-file] functions, which then causes Matlab to stop execution and open the file. However, it's almost never helpful to debug inside of the built-in file, so this ends up disrupting my workflow. Might there be a way to set things up so that Matlab backs out of the built-in file in the debugger (never opening it), leaving me at the function call?

Comment: +1: I've never found a way to tackle this *in general*...I always just accept that I'm going inside the built-in and then immediately type `dbup` (and or repeat that) to go to the relevant context...I'm very curious to find a solution to this nuisance too.

Comment: Other than manually looking at the stack via `dbstack` when the code generates an error, I also have not found a way to do what you are asking.  This is something that I've wanted in MATLAB for a while but I know no built-in way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Rody's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448311/2052625) answer and feedback from Mathworks, this is the closest you can get at this point (R2016b):

```
S = dbstack('-completenames');

builtins    = ~cellfun('isempty', strfind({S(:).file}, matlabroot()));
stack_depth = find(~builtins, 1, 'first');

hDocument = matlab.desktop.editor.findOpenDocument(S(1).file);
matlab.desktop.editor.openAndGoToLine(S(stack_depth).file,S(stack_depth).line);
hDocument.close();

if stack_depth == 2
    dbup();
end
```

This shortcut will:

1. Open up the closest user function to the correct line.
2. Close the builtin function that opened when the error was thrown.
3. *If* the error happened only one level away from a user function, switch to that workspace.

The problem is that dbup() only works once - after the call, execution in the script stops. There's no function to switch to an arbitrary place in the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Although I've never found a way to tackle this problem *properly*, it's fairly easy to hack together a workaround:

1. Create a script containing something along these lines:

   ```
   S = dbstack();

   file_paths  = cellfun(@which, {S.file}, 'UniformOutput', false);
   builtins    = ~cellfun('isempty', strfind(file_paths, matlabroot()));
   stack_depth = find(~builtins, 1, 'first');

   for ii = 1:stack_depth-1
       dbup(); end
   ```
2. Save it somewhere that makes sense to you, and place a [shortcut to it in the MATLAB toolbar](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/create-matlab-shortcuts-to-rerun-commands.html).

Then, whenever this problem occurs, you just click on your little shortcut, which will automatically take you to the first non-builtin function in the debug stack.

Comment: This is pretty much what Mathworks suggested. It looks like this only works if stack_depth == 2 though, because as soon as you call dbup() the callback stops execution. I can't seem to find a way to move to an arbitrary place in the stack.